# Change color to HTML input value

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of input fields on my webpage as you can see

[image]

When I edit (for example) the scores of GP1, using a `onchange` event, each other score will automatically update. I'd like that when these results update, the color of that 2 input in the TOTAL row changes.

In this case the '13' should be red and the '15' should be green.

I thought to use some CSS code but I don't know how to use it with an `onchange` event. Any suggestion?

This is the code:

```
<td valign="bottom" width="110px">
<p align="center"><b>Home Clan</b></p>
</td>
<td valign="bottom" width="110px">
<p align="center"><b>Opponent Clan</b></p>
</td>
<td valign="bottom" width="110px">
<p align="center"><b> + / -  </b></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="40px;" width="40px">
<p align="center"><b>GP1</b></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input id="h1" type="text" name="h1" value="0" style="width:70px" onchange="calc();"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input id="o1" type="text" name="o1" value="0" style="width:70px" onchange="calc();"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input readonly id="diff1" type="text" name="diff1" style="width:70px"></p>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="40px;" width="40px">
<p align="center"><b>GP2</b></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input id="h2" type="text" name="h2" value="0" style="width:70px" onchange="calc();"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input id="o2" type="text" name="o2" value="0" style="width:70px" onchange="calc();"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input readonly  id="diff2" type="text" name="diff2" style="width:70px"></p>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="40px;" width="40px">
<p align="center"><b>GP3</b></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input id="h3" type="text" name="h3" value="0" style="width:70px" onchange="calc();"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input id="o3" type="text" name="o3" value="0" style="width:70px" onchange="calc();"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input readonly  id="diff3" type="text" name="diff3" style="width:70px"></p>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="13px">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="40px;" width="40px">
<b>TOTAL</b>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input readonly  id="htot" type="text" name="htot" style="width:70px"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input readonly id="otot" type="text" name="otot" style="width:70px"></p>
</td>
<td width="110px">
<p align="center"><input readonly id="difftot" type="text" name="difftot" style="width:70px"></p>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please copy/paste your code so that we can help you ?

Comment: You can't do it with a css selector, so you have to assign a css class or add an inline style with JavaScript.

Comment: @BalintBako yes but the problem is that I don't really know how to do that, I've googled about this but I can't understand how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question wasn't very clear but i think that you want to color in red the lower score and in green the highest.

You define a function like so, that will called in your `onChange` event.

```
function color()
{

    htot = document.getElementById('htot');
    otot = document.getElementById('otot');

    if ( htot.value < otot.value ) {
        htot.style.color = 'red';
        otot.style.color = 'green'; } else {
        otot.style.color = 'red';
        htot.style.color = 'green'; }
}
```

You can call this function at the end of your `calc()` function for instance.

Comment: You're welcome. This code i posted can be greatly improved by the way.

Comment: You wrote "ttot.style.color = 'green'; }", it's htot :) fix that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add class total on your TOTAL input and use this jQuery to change color ..

```
$("input").change(function () {
    $('.total').css("background", "orange");
});
```

Comment: Uhmm question is `Change color to HTML input value` so you need `$('.total').css("color", "orange");` right?

Comment: y color sry i thought background-color XD